# Can't execute a callback when overriding mongoose exec function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, caching, redis

I'm trying to implement an automatic caching system where any normal call to mongodb using mongoose uses redis as a middleman to cache it. And the problem is, I've gotten storing it, fetching it, but I can't use a callback. I've dug forever and can't find out how to call it. I've found some chunks ( How mongoose calls ) but I can't find the piece that is the actual callback I specified. Through some investigation, I found that returning doesn't do anything, and the only way I could figure out how to callback was using mongooseExec.apply(this, arguments) but that doesn't help when I need to call it once fetching because calling .apply also fetches from mongodb which I don't want if it's already cached. Here's the reduced code:

```
const mongooseExec = mongoose.Query.prototype.exec;
mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = async function () {
          const key = await JSON.stringify({
            ...this.getQuery(),
            collection: this.mongooseCollection.name,
            op: this.op,
            options: this.options,
          });
          let cached = await self.redisClient.get(key);
          let result;
          if (cached) {
            console.log("CACHED");
            return await JSON.parse(cached)
          } else {
            result = await mongooseExec.apply(this, arguments);
          }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The callback is passed as an argument to the exec function.  For example, in [find](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/query.js#L2286):

```
this.exec(callback);
```

Your exec function needs to accept a callback function as its first argument.